# Wait till the form gets submitted in capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, cucumber, capybara

I am new to capybara and Ruby on  Rails world. I am writing cucumber features for Rails application using capybara.

I am using sleep statements in step definition file to wait till the page (or rather form) gets submitted.
But I observed that the page submission time varies. So how can I tell capybara to wait till the next page gets loaded or some action happens ?

```
expect(page).to have_css(".alert.in.alert-success" , text: arg1,exact: true)
```

I have tried the above way to wait but it did not work. And I found that wait_until is deprecated in capybara2.0 
So can anyone tell me how do I wait in capybara till the page gets submitted or till some action happens ?

Answer (score 0):

capybara is usually very good at waiting for elements to appear. but you are having issues you can trying increasing the default wait time or you can manually wait for it. here is an article that might help

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara

Answer (score 0):

In the example expect you provided, the exact:true option doesn't relate to the :text option passed, but rather to locators passed to the "selectors" provided by Capybara (:button, :field, etc).  Since you're not using any of those selectors the option isn't really doing anything. To have Capybara wait for the next page to load you need to have it look for something that would be visible on the next page but no on the current page

```
expect(page).to have_css('.alert.in.alert-success', text: 'This is only on the next page')
```

will cause Capybara to wait up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time for a visible element with the given classes containing the given text to be on the page.  If you want to match exact text in the element you can pass a regex

```
expect(page).to have_css('.alert.in.alert-success', text: /\AThis is only on the next page\Z/)
```

If the page is not loading fast enough you can either increase the value of Capybara.default_max_wait_time or you can override the value used for a specific call by using the :wait option

```
expect(page).to have_css('.alert.in.alert-success', text: 'This is only on the next page', wait: 10)  # wait up to 10 seconds for the element with given classes containing given text to become visible
```